# How to add a try catch for a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, try-catch

I have a stored procedure 'Class_set' which is triggered to when user attempts to add a class to the database. The stored procedure checks if there are any clashes in the database and if no clashes exist it inserts the class to the database.

Currently if a clash exists it throws a 51000 error but I want the error to be visible on the front end using a label or a panel to display the appropriate message. I tried to use try catch but it wasn't successful.

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE procedure dbo.Class_set ( 
   @moduledata int 
  , @startdatedata datetime 
  , @enddatedata datetime 
  , @classtypedata int 
  , @roomcodedata int 
  , @starttimedata int 
  , @endtimedata int 
  , @recurrencedata int 
  , @daydata int 
) as 
begin; 
  set nocount, xact_abort on; 
  /* temp table */ 
 select 
    DayId = @daydata 
  , ModuleId =@moduledata 
  , ClassTypeId = @classtypedata 
  , ClassScheduleStartTimeId = @starttimedata 
  , ClassScheduleEndTimeId = @endtimedata 
  , RoomCodeId = @roomcodedata 
  , StartTime= convert(datetime,c.Date) + s.StartTime 
  , EndTime = convert(datetime,c.Date) + e.EndTime 
  , RecurrenceId = @recurrencedata 
into #temp_class 
from Calendar c 
  cross apply ( 
    select StartTime = convert(datetime,ClassTime) 
    from ClassSchedule 
    where ClassScheduleId = @starttimedata 
    ) as s 
  cross apply ( 
   select EndTime = convert(datetime,ClassTime) 
   from ClassSchedule 
   where ClassScheduleId = @endtimedata 
   ) as e 
where c.Date >= @startdatedata 
  and c.Date <= @enddatedata 
  and c.isWeekDay = 1 
  and ( @recurrencedata != 2 
      or (@recurrencedata = 2 and c.DayOfWeek = @daydata) 
       ); 

/* check for conflicts */ 
if exists( 
  select 1 
  from dbo.[Class] c 
     inner join #temp_class t 
       on c.RoomCodeId = t.RoomCodeId 
      and t.EndTime > c.StartTime 
      and c.EndTime > t.StartTime 
  ) 
begin; 
    throw 51000, 'Room conflict exists',1; 
    return -1; 
    end; 

/* insert */ 
insert into dbo.[Class] (DayId, ModuleId, ClassTypeId 
    , ClassScheduleStartTimeId, ClassScheduleEndTimeId 
    , RoomCodeId, StartTime, EndTime, RecurrenceId ) 
select DayId, ModuleId, ClassTypeId 
   , ClassScheduleStartTimeId, ClassScheduleEndTimeId 
   , RoomCodeId, StartTime, EndTime, RecurrenceId 
from #temp_class 

end;
go
```

My method which calls the stored procedure:

```
  internal void insert_days( int daydata, int moduledata, int? recurrencedata, DateTime startdatedata, DateTime enddatedata, int classtypedata, int roomcodedata, int starttimedata, int endtimedata, string totalday)
    {

        {

            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Class_set", myConnection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@daydata", daydata);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduledata", moduledata);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classtypedata", classtypedata);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdatedata", startdatedata);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddatedata", enddatedata);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomcodedata", roomcodedata);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttimedata", starttimedata);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtimedata", endtimedata);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recurrencedata", recurrencedata);

                    myConnection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

My attempt at the try catch:

```
  internal void insert_days(int daydata, int moduledata, int? recurrencedata, DateTime startdatedata, DateTime enddatedata, int classtypedata, int roomcodedata, int starttimedata, int endtimedata, string totalday) 
{ 
  { 
    try 
    { 
       string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; 

      SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 

     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Class_set", myConnection)) 
        { 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@daydata", daydata); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduledata", moduledata); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classtypedata", classtypedata); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdatedata", startdatedata); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddatedata", enddatedata); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomcodedata", roomcodedata); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttimedata", starttimedata); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtimedata", endtimedata); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recurrencedata", recurrencedata); 

        myConnection.Open(); 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
} 
 catch (SqlException ex) 
  { 
      switch (ex.Number) 
       { 
         case 51000: 
         Console.WriteLine("Error: Clashes exist with your current Room selection"); 
         break; 

         default:
         Console.WriteLine("Success: No clashes exist with your current Room selection");            

      } 
   } 
 }  
}
```

Image of current error thrown: 
[image]

Comment: Have you attempted to run the stored procedure explicitly (such as directly  in SSMS) to ensure it is throwing the error you are expecting? This can help rule out that the problem is in the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have not done this. Im using Console.WriteLine and I don't even know where this is supposed to display the text. Ideally I want to use a label but I just dont know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your SQL in a try catch.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Class_set ( 
   @moduledata int 
  , @startdatedata datetime 
  , @enddatedata datetime 
  , @classtypedata int 
  , @roomcodedata int 
  , @starttimedata int 
  , @endtimedata int 
  , @recurrencedata int 
  , @daydata int 
) AS 
BEGIN 
    set nocount, xact_abort on; 
    /* temp table */ 

    BEGIN TRY
        select 
            DayId = @daydata 
          , ModuleId =@moduledata 
          , ClassTypeId = @classtypedata 
          , ClassScheduleStartTimeId = @starttimedata 
          , ClassScheduleEndTimeId = @endtimedata 
          , RoomCodeId = @roomcodedata 
          , StartTime= convert(datetime,c.Date) + s.StartTime 
          , EndTime = convert(datetime,c.Date) + e.EndTime 
          , RecurrenceId = @recurrencedata 
        into 
            #temp_class 
        from 
            Calendar c 
            cross apply ( 
            select StartTime = convert(datetime,ClassTime) 
            from ClassSchedule 
            where ClassScheduleId = @starttimedata 
            ) as s 
            cross apply ( 
            select EndTime = convert(datetime,ClassTime) 
            from ClassSchedule 
            where ClassScheduleId = @endtimedata 
            ) as e 
        where 
            c.Date >= @startdatedata 
            and c.Date <= @enddatedata 
            and c.isWeekDay = 1 
            and ( @recurrencedata != 2 
                or (@recurrencedata = 2 and c.DayOfWeek = @daydata) 
            ); 

            /* insert */ 
            insert into dbo.[Class] (DayId, ModuleId, ClassTypeId 
                , ClassScheduleStartTimeId, ClassScheduleEndTimeId 
                , RoomCodeId, StartTime, EndTime, RecurrenceId ) 
            select DayId, ModuleId, ClassTypeId 
               , ClassScheduleStartTimeId, ClassScheduleEndTimeId 
               , RoomCodeId, StartTime, EndTime, RecurrenceId 
            from #temp_class 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        THROW
    END CATCH;
END
GO
```

Add a scalar function to do the validation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RoomConflict
(
    @RoomCode INT,
    @StartTime TIME(7),
    @EndTime TIME(7)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM 
            dbo.Class A 
        WHERE 
            A.RoomCodeId = @RoomCode AND @EndTime > A.StartTime AND A.EndTime > @StartTime)
END
GO
```

Then add a constraint to the dbo.Class table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Class] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_NoRoomConflict] CHECK (
    [dbo].[RoomConflict]([RoomCodeId],[StartTime],[EndTime]) = 0
)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Class] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_NoRoomConflict]
GO
```

Comment: I appreciate that. It already throws an error. See my recent image attachment. I just don't want the user to see that screen. I want them to see text on the front endif you get me?

Comment: well, you'll have to develop your app to handle the errors and the presentation of them

Comment: I know Im just not sure how to do this. I don't know the sql syntax to use to in order to reference it on the code behind. How would you approach this if you wanted text to display on the front end?

Comment: what kind of app are you building?

Comment: Im using ASP.NET with C# to build a webforms website. Currently I have AddClassSchedule.aspx where the user inserts all the details to add a class, they click submitbtn which has an onclick function insertbutton_Click which then passes through all the paramterised values to UpdateTimetable.cs where the insert_days method is. insert_days then runs the stored procedure. The SP carries out the clash check and inserts the class data if no error is thrown, but if an error is thrown the user is directed to that page in the screenshot.

Comment: what about this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ill try out all these methods to see if it works :) I feel theres a simple solution!

Comment: Working through the official documentation is usually the best place to start

Answer (score 0):

I was able to edit the Web.Config file to add customErrors which redirects the user to a new page on the website where I have explained the issue. It is not ideal as I would liked to have displayed something on the page they are currently on but this is the only solution I can find at the moment.

```
   <configuration>
      <system.web>
             <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx?handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config">
              <error statusCode="510" redirect="ErrorPage.aspx?msg=404&amp;handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config"/>
              </customErrors>
       </system.web>
  </configuration>
```